# Slow Powershell function. How to Improve?

Tags: powershell

I have written the below Powershell function to call an F5 unit.  It loops round for each server and gets each individual stat and then executes a SQL SMO call.

The code is running really slowly and i think i have discounted the SQL call as the cause.

How can the powershell be improved?

```
function Print-VServerStats()
{

param($virtual_server);


$VirtualServerStatistics = (Get-F5.iControl).LocalLBVirtualServer.get_statistics( (, $virtual_server) );
$VirtualServerStatisticEntry = $VirtualServerStatistics.statistics[0];
$Statistics = $VirtualServerStatisticEntry.statistics | ? {$_.type -eq "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_CURRENT_CONNECTIONS" -or
                                                           $_.type -eq "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS" -or
                                                           $_.type -eq "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS"};

foreach ($Statistic in $Statistics)
{
  $val = Convert-To64Bit $Statistic.value.high $Statistic.value.low;

  switch ($Statistic.type) {
    "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_CURRENT_CONNECTIONS" {
     $label = "Current Connections";
    }
     "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS" {
     $label = "Max Connections";
    }
      "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS" {
     $label = "Total Connections";
    }
  }
    $profcmd.Parameters["@property"].Value = $SrceName
    $profcmd.Parameters["@propertyDesc"].Value = $label
    $profcmd.Parameters["@ValDim1"].Value = $virtual_server
    $profcmd.Parameters["@value"].Value = $val 
    $profcmd.Parameters["@Timestamp"].Value = $t
    [void]$profcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "slow"? Have you measured what statement takes most of the time? I think the bottleneck will be external source (sql server), not PowerShell.

Comment: Just FYI, you can use the `Measure-Command` cmdlet for performance analysis. As Stej says, its highly unlikely that PowerShell is at fault for being "slow".

Comment: Thanks, did not know about the Measure-Command cmdlet.  Will use it and see if i can identify the exact cause

Answer (score 0):

We have an F5 BigIP and we've noticed that the UI on the device is *really really slow*. We haven't traced the cause, but it is very likely your delay is sourcing on the F5 device itself. Measure-Command on

```
$VirtualServerStatistics = (Get-F5.iControl).LocalLBVirtualServer.get_statistics( (, $virtual_server) );
```

Should show it if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to test without having F5 but maybe you can shorten/improve the code by replacing:

```
$Statistics = $VirtualServerStatisticEntry.statistics | ? {$_.type -eq "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_CURRENT_CONNECTIONS" -or
                                                           $_.type -eq "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS" -or
                                                           $_.type -eq "STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS"};
```

With

```
 $Statistics = $VirtualServerStatisticEntry.statistics | ? {$_.type -match '^STATISTIC_CLIENT_SIDE_(CURRENT|MAXIMUM|TOTAL)_CONNECTIONS?' }
```

Comment: I think this could save several miliseconds, but Andrew would like to save some seconds (at least).